# Pulling columns of dataframe into separate dataframe, then replacing duplicates with mean values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, mean

I'm new to the world of python so I apologize in advance if this question seems pretty rudimentary. I'm trying to pull columns of one dataframe into a separate dataframe. I want to replace the duplicate columns from the first dataframe with one column that contains the mean values into the second dataframe. I hope this makes sense!

To provide some background, I am tracking gene expression over certain time points. I have a dataframe that is 17 rows x 33 columns. Every row in this data frame corresponds to a particular exon. Every column on this data frame corresponds to a time-point (AGE).

The dataframe looks like this:[image: image of my dataframe]

Some of these columns contain the same name (age) and I'd like to calculate the mean of ONLY the columns with the same name, so that, for example, I get one column for "12 pcw" rather than three separate columns for "12 pcw." After which I hope to pull these values from the first dataframe into a second dataframe for averaged values.

I'm hoping to use a **for loop** to loop through each age (column) to get the average expression across the subjects.

I will explain my process so far below:

#1) Get list of UNIQUE string names from age list

`unique_ages = set(column_names)`

#2) Create an empty dataframe that gives an outline of what I want my averaged data to fit/be put in

`mean_df = pd.DataFrame(index=exons, columns=unique_ages)`

#3) Now I want to loop through each age to get the average expression across the donors present. This is where I'm trying to utilize a ***for loop*** to create a pipeline to process other data frames that I will be working with in the future.

```
for age in unique_ages:
    print(age)
    age_df = pd.DataFrame() ##pull columns of df as separate df that have this string 
    if len(age_df.columns) > 1: ##check if df has >1 SAME column, if so, take avg across SAME columns 
        mean = df.mean(axis=1)
        mean_df[age] = mean
    else:
        ## just pull out the values and put them into your temp_df
```

#4) Now, with my new averaged array (or same array if multiple ages NOT present), I want to place this array into my 'temp_df' under the appropriate columns. I understand that I should use the 'age' variable provided by the for loop to get the proper locationname of the column in my temp df. However I'm not sure how to do this. This has all been quite a steep learning curve and I feel like it's a simple solution but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a `for loop` (there often isn't with Pandas :)). You can simply use `df.groupby(lambda x:x, axis=1).mean()`. An example:

```
data = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col2']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=cols)

#    col1  col2  col2
# 0     1     2     3
# 1     4     5     6

df = df.groupby(lambda x:x, axis=1).mean()

#    col1  col2
# 0   1.0   2.5
# 1   4.0   5.5
```

The `groupby` function takes another function (the lambda) which basically means that it will insert each column name, and that it will return the group that column belongs to. In our case, we just want the column name itself to be the group. So, on the third column named `col2`, it will say 'this column belongs to group named `col2`' which already exists (because the second column was passed earlier). You then provide the aggregation you want, in this case the `mean()`.